# Cuda out of Memory in Pytorch: weird behavior and how to solve it

Tags: python, pytorch, out-of-memory, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to train a model ([convLSTM](https://github.com/NVlabs/conv-tt-lstm)) using Pytorch for video prediction. My "videos" are a list of images of dimensions 350x350 (frames), and I give N frames as input and need to predict N frames in output.

For train my network I am currently using a NVIDIA V100 with 12 cores and 12GB of RAM. My inputs and ouputs are 5-th order tensors of size [batch_size, n_frames, channels, height, width].

The problem is that even setting the bare minimum, i.e.:
num_workers=1,batch_size = 1, size-training-set= 1 (just 1 video sample of 16 frames! - note that with lower than 16 frames works)
I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 24.00 MiB (GPU 0; 32.00 GiB total capacity; 28.14 GiB already allocated; 96.54 MiB free; 28.55 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.
```

I really don't know how to get rid of this error. My training size is about more than 10K samples of 20 frames each and I cannot even run my code with 1 sample.

I saw that this error is common, but cannot find a way to solve it (since everything is already at the minimum..). I tried to check my memory usage with `nvidia-smi` and `torch.cuda.memory_summary()` but could not get any insight. Also, `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` does not help.

I see however that pytorch allocate a lot of space for itself, is it normal? In the code I don't do nothing weird, I just check if cuda is available as `device` and then set

```
model.to(device)
if multi_gpu: 
    model = nn.DataParallel(model)
```

the error generates at this point in my training loop:

```
prediction = model(inputs, 
            input_frames  = train_data.n_frames_input, 
            future_frames = train_data.n_frames_output, 
            output_frames = train_data.n_frames_output,      
            teacher_forcing = True, 
            scheduled_sampling_ratio = scheduled_sampling_ratio)
```

Any insights?

EDIT: resizing the pictures to lower dimensions (half of the original quality) seems to help.